# multiply from two tables mysql error

Tags: mysql

How do I join the two respective table below?

```
routing
routing_id |work_center_id |description |machine|UOM |production_hour


work_center 
work_center_id| routing_id |production_price
```

I would like to multiply production_hour from routing table and production_price from work center.

I tried this but it don't work:

```
$query1 = "SELECT SUM(r.production_price * wc.production_hour) '
   FROM routing r, work_center wc 
   WHERE wc.work_center_id = r.routing_id";
```

Comment: first remove ' from your query

Comment: I've removed the '. Unknown column 'r.production_price' in 'field list' is the error.

Comment: because `production_price` column is in `work_center` table

Comment: @PathikVejani, absolutely agree!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typo in query and use explicit joins.

```
SELECT (wc.production_price * r.production_hour) AS production_cost
FROM routing r
INNER JOIN work_center wc ON r.routing_id = wc.work_center_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Query:

```
SELECT (r.production_hour * wc.production_price) AS cost
FROM routing r, work_center wc 
WHERE wc.work_center_id = r.routing_id
```